# Facebook FQL not working properly for photos/albums

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The following FQL was working properly and then for some reason it doesn't:

```
@userPhotos = @rest.fql_query("select src_big, src_big_width,src_big_height FROM photo     WHERE album_object_id IN 
                   (SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me())")
```

It produces a list of "one" album - the last album instead of producing a list of all albums owned by the user. I'm using FB explorer to check the FQL. It used to work properly but not now. Have you experienced that problem?

Comment: This is a temporary, I hope, problem with FQL. This bug was reported by a couple of other developers.

Answer (score 0):

what is album_object_id ?? ... i dont think this exists. isn't it

you can check objects here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/

Answer (score 0):

Same query can be done using AID for both photo and album. It works fine for me.

Does your query working now? (if user1388066 was right and that was a bug)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by the following bug, which is now resolved: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/421883904529161